# Grouping query results

Tags: database

I have this small and simple sql query.

```
  $query = \Drupal::database()->select('users_field_data', 'ufd');
  $query->fields('ufd', ['uid', 'name', 'mail', 'status']);
  $query->orderBy('ufd.status', 'Desc');

  $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Result of this is an array of Objects which include the fields from the query above. Here's a sample:

```
[
stdClass Object
(
    [uid] => 2
    [name] => Test 1
    [mail] => test@test1.com
    [status] => 1
)
stdClass Object
(
    [uid] => 3
    [name] => Test 3
    [mail] => test@test2.com
    [status] => 0
)
]
```

So my question is how can i group the results by the field status, so that i have and array of results with the index of the status? I think i can get the results with GroupBy, but no luck so far.

Example/Result wanted:

```
[status_key_1] => [
stdClass Object
(
    [uid] => 2
    [name] => Test 1
    [mail] => test@test1.com
    [status] => 1
)stdClass Object
(
    [uid] => 3
    [name] => Test 2
    [mail] => test@test2.com
    [status] => 1
)
]
[status_key_0] => [
stdClass Object
(
    [uid] => 4
    [name] => Test 4
    [mail] => test@test4.com
    [status] => 0
)stdClass Object
(
    [uid] => 5
    [name] => Test 5
    [mail] => test@test5.com
    [status] => 0
)
]
```

Where `status_key_0` and `status_key_1` are essentially 0 and 1, since those are the only two values drupal allows, but i didn't want to put them directly in the example as some would think i wanted a auto-incremented associated array.

~p.s. i know i can sort the result of the query, and that's what i'm doing, but having an already sorted array is best practice and a good solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SQL GroupBy is generally used with expressions to get counts and other stats.  I'm not sure it will be more efficient than just sorting.  That said...

You should be able to add a [groupBy clause](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21Select.php/function/Select%3A%3AgroupBy/8.2.x) to your query. You will have to add all fields to it in order to keep SQL happy.  E.g.:

```
$query->groupBy('udf.status')->groupBy('udf.uid')...
```

Note: I believe that the SQL standard is deprecating the use of groupby without an aggregation function in the select clause.

Answer (score 0):

To get this result, you must do two SQL queries.

Please, try this code:

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('users_field_data', 'ufd');
$query->fields('ufd', ['status']);
$query->groupBy('ufd.status');
$query->orderBy('ufd.status', 'Asc');
$results_query1 = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

$results=array();

foreach ($results_query1 as $delta => $result) {  
  $query = \Drupal::database()->select('users_field_data', 'ufd');
  $query->fields('ufd', ['uid', 'name', 'mail', 'status']);
  $query->condition('ufd.status', $result->status);
  $query->orderBy('ufd.status', 'Desc');
  $result_query2 = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

  $results['status_key_'.$result->status]=$result_query2;
}

print_r($results);
```

The result will be:

```
Array
(
    [status_key_0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uid] => 0
                    [name] => 
                    [mail] => 
                    [status] => 0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uid] => 21
                    [name] => b
                    [mail] => b@b.com
                    [status] => 0
                )

        )

    [status_key_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uid] => 1
                    [name] => admin
                    [mail] => localhost@localhost.com
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uid] => 3
                    [name] => a
                    [mail] => a@a.com
                    [status] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

An example of how to access the information of this variable:

```
$results['status_key_1'][1]->uid
```

The result is:

```
3
```